# How to focus dialog window?

Tags: java, swing

I want to show a pop-up notification from a minimized (console) window.

Here is the code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

//...

frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.toFront();

int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, panel, "test",
        JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
        null, options, options[0]);
```

The window pops up and it's on top, but it isn't focused.
The title bar is gray, while it should be dark blue.

What should I do to fix this ?

PS: if it's relevant, I'm running it on windows 7.

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Your JFrame wants focus and your JOptionPane wants focus.  Only one window will have focus.  Remove the two frame methods, setAlwaysOnTop and toFront, in your code.

Comment: Gilbert Le Blanc, if I remove them, the window does not pop pu al all. It's not visible in the task bar and olny accessible via Alt-Tab.